# Не срабатывает js в infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня на сайте подключен infinite scroll. Я решил поставить рекламные блоки, но они в js и не отображаются на последующих страницах подгружаемых AJAX. Может их нужно как то обернуть чтоб они отображались? пробовал сделать колхозно так с проверкой блока на пустоту и если пусто, то подгрузить. Сработало, но есть нюанс.

```js
    let elem = document.getElementById('one');
    if (!elem.childNodes.length) { 
  let one = document.createElement('script');
    one.src = '/blocks/1.js';
    elem.appendChild(one);
     }
```

Проблема в том что блоков много с каждой подгружаемой страницей, а скрипт рассчитан на 1 раз. как можно реализовать, чтоб с каждой подгружаемой страницей шла проверка div с id one и если он с блоком, то пропустить, если пустой то вставить блок?
Помогите пожалуйста( я нуб в js, может есть решение проще, но пока такое пришло в голову...